# Writing nested lists into a .txt file

Tags: python

Given a list of lists where each inner list consists of a string and a float, and an open file for writing, write the contents of each inner list as a line in the file. Each line of the file should be the string followed by the float separated by a comma. Close the file when done.

```
def write_avg(L, out_file):  
    '''(list, file) -> NoneType
    >>> L = [['a', 2.0], ['b', 3.0], ['c', 4.0]]  
    a, 2.0  
    b, 3.0  
    c, 4.0  
    '''
    L1 = []  
    L2 = []  
    myList = []    
    for item in L:  
        if item == str:  
            item.append(L1)  
        elif item == float:  
            item.append(L2)  
        else:  
            return "error"  
        myList.append(L1, L2)  
    out_file.writelines(myList)
```

How do I add a list to each new line of a .txt document??

Comment: What format do you want each line of the output to look like?

Comment: If the list was [['a', 2.0], ['b', 3.0], ['c', 4.0]]

Comment: Then on the .txt file it should have  a, 2.0     b, 3.0      c, 4.0 each on a new line

Comment: Don't invent your own format, just use an existing metaformat like JSON. Further, `return "error"` is rubbish, throw an exception on failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Python and tables I recommend the pandas library.
The output can be achieved in one row like this:

```
import pandas as pd

L = [['a', 2.0], ['b', 3.0], ['c', 4.0]] 

pd.DataFrame(L).to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tabulate:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

with open(file, "a") as writedfile:
    writedfile.write(tabulate(my_list, headers=headers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `python` list expression you can do something like this:

```
myList = ["{0}, {1}".format(x1, x2) for (x1, x2) in L]
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.writelines(myList)
```

This will create for

```
L = [['a', 2.0], ['b', 3.0], ['c', 4.0]]
```

this output:

> a, 2.0
>   b, 3.0
>   c, 4.0

Comment: FlashTek, you don't get an error "out_file.writelines(myList)builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'writelines'" When running the code?

Comment: @CSVMasterXD I expected your object with the name `out_file` has a method called `writelines`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst = [['a', 2.0], ['b', 3.0], ['c', 4.0]]

filename = 'test.txt'

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
     for sublist in lst:
          line = "{}, {}\n".format(sublist[0], sublist[1])
          f.write(line)
```

The output written to the file:

```
a, 2.0
b, 3.0
c, 4.0
```

Comment: Oh that is very understandable. can you replace 'test.txt' with a variable -> open(x, 'w') as f: representing any files, it should still be perfect right? ( automated tester uses many different files to check)

Comment: @CSVMasterXD, yes, you can. Just changed it accordingly.